# Fetching data using Http in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a simple application in angular 2 to fetch data using Http.
I created two classes employee-list and employee-detail and a service with the name 
employee.service.ts which makes an Http call and recieve the observable and map it.

I also create a folder in src with the name apidata in which i kept my data to be fetched 
in the employeedata.json file.

And later subscribe to the observable and assign the data to local variable in the view.

My code is being compiled successfully .But iam unable to fetch data.

### Below shown is my code snippets

### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Employee</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading.....</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

### app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Http, Response} from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EmployeeListComponent } from './employee-list.component';
import { EmployeeDetailComponent } from './employee-detail.component';
import { EmployeeService } from './employee.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EmployeeListComponent,
    EmployeeDetailComponent
  ],

  imports: [ BrowserModule, HttpModule ],

  providers: [EmployeeService],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { EmployeeService } from './employee.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',

  providers: [EmployeeService]


})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

### app.component.html

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:justify-all;">
  <h3>
    Welcome to {{title}}!
  </h3>
 <h4> Random Company</h4>
  <h4> ...........</h4>

  <employee-list></employee-list>
  <employee-detail></employee-detail>
```

### employee-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EmployeeService } from './employee.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'employee-list',
    template: `<h4>Employee List</h4>'
                <ul *ngFor=" let employee of employees ">
                <li>{{employee.name}}</li>
                </ul>`
})

export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit{
employees = [];

constructor(private _employeeService:EmployeeService){}
ngOnInit(){
this._employeeService.getEmployees()
.subscribe(resEmployeeData => this.employees = resEmployeeData);
}
}
```

### employee-detail.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EmployeeService } from './employee.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'employee-detail',
    template: `<h4>Employee Details</h4>'
                <ul *ngFor=" let employee of employees ">
                <li>{{employee.id}}.{{employee.name}}-{{employee.gender}}</li>
                </ul>`
})

export class EmployeeDetailComponent implements OnInit{
employees = [];

constructor(private _employeeService:EmployeeService){}
ngOnInit(){
this.employees = this._employeeService.getEmployees();
}
}
```

### employee.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class EmployeeService {

private _url: string = "apidata/employeedata.json"

constructor(private _http: Http){}

    getEmployees(){
    return this._http.get(this._url)
    .map((response:Response) => response.json() );
}}
```

Can anybody please let me know what is that i am missing in my application.
 Why my application isn't fetching data ?

Comment: have you logged out what you get back from the request? have you tried adding headers to the call?

Comment: can you check in your network tab of your browser what does this api return?

Comment: I am new to angular .i don't know much about adding headers to the call.can you please guide me according to my application.

Comment: @Deepak Jha.. Its only returning me the template view but not fetching the data from the file employeedata.json

Comment: when i hit F5 on my Network tab ,the employeedata.json file gave status of 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must subscribe to observable which is return from your service.
You can do this in your component (observable.subscribe()) or in your template:

employee-detail.component.ts

```
<ul *ngFor=" let employee of employees | async">
```

Comment: The above statement i added in my employee-detail.component.ts,but i am still unable to fetch data.

Comment: can you check network tab of your browser what does api return ?

Comment: Its only returning me the template view but not fetching the data from the file employeedata.json

Comment: Does the request go to your appdata/employee data.json file in your network tab ? What http status is return ?

Comment: when i hit F5 on my Network tab ,the employeedata.json file gave status of 404.

Comment: Can you pull out your apidata to the root of the project and then try ?

Comment: And use url ./apidata/employeedata.json in your service.

Comment: Its giving me this error in console.compiler.js:466 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Response: (?).

Comment: Remove providers from app.component.ts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158864/discussion-between-heena-and-pioro90).

Comment: Thanks a lot,my application is successfully executed and its fetching data from both the classes

Comment: hi ... can you please help me out with this issue...............https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51441961/unable-to-build-the-asp-net-core-2-0-angular-2-4-user-registration-and-login