# Unable to build the ASP.NET Core 2.0 + Angular 2/4 - User Registration and Login application

Tags: asp.net, angular

I am trying to deploy the ASP.NET Core 2.0 + Angular 2/4 - User Registration and Login application on IIS server taken from the link https://www.pointblankdevelopment.com.au/blog/134/aspnet-core-20-angular-24-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-example

I am able to successfully import the project in Visual Studio Community 2017 and run the application through terminal using **"npm i"** and **"npm start"**

But when Iam trying to build the project using the command **"ng build --prod --base-href /loginreg/"**, I am getting the error as shown below in the image below.....

[image]

Then again i deleted **nodemodules** folder and **package-lock.json** file from the project and run the cmd "npm install" , "npm start" and then "ng build --prod --base-href /loginreg/", but its not working.

I also tried to run the following command **"ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.4"** by referring the various solutions..But again iam facing the same issue.

Later i also tried **"ng build --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false"** command ,i am unable to resolve it..

Can anybody please solve my issue...?